# Inaccuracy in timing an audio file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio

I was playing around with JavaScript audio and I noticed that when I time an audio file the number I get back isn't equal to the length of the audio file. The code I'm using goes something like this:

```
var audio = new Audio("sound.mp3");
var start, stop;
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    stop = performance.now() - start;
});

start = performance.now();
audio.play();
```

When sound.mp3 is only 1000 ms long, I'll get a value back from `stop` that's anywhere from 50 ms to 350 ms larger than the length of the audio file. Does anyone know why this happens? Does it actually take that long to play the audio file?

Comment: the delay is caused by several things that need to be done taking time. starting playback takes time; the audio must be parsed and buffered, an output negotiated with the OS, etc. ended() also must fire AFTER the stop, which could be anytime after, but at any rate, it's not instant. if you play() before you now(), it will be closer. if you play, then pause, then play() then now(), it will be even less off since the audio loading part wont' be counted by the timer.

Comment: fwiw: there are lots of events on the audio tag that provide opertunity for high-resolution timestamp gathering, allowing a running offset to be calculated, which could show just where and when you are getting behind, as well as providing opportunity to compensate mid-way to arrive at a very close parallel, to within the granularity of the audio format itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MP3 files are not sample-accurate.  MP3 works in the time domain with fixed frame sizes.  A typical frame size is 26 milliseconds.  This is the minimum time resolution you get with MP3.

Your audio file isn't exactly 1 second long unless you have some really odd sample rate that is divisible evenly into one second... and if you had that, it wouldn't work in MP3 anyway.

The next problem you have is with starting the audio for MP3.  MP3 audio doesn't start immediately on the first frame.  Different encoders use different amounts of padding.  Playing "gapless" MP3 files have the same problem.

Finally, your browser isn't always what's doing the audio playback.  Very often there is an underlying library that handles it, and sometimes these libraries don't link up so well to the browser.  The browser may know when the audio started and when it stopped, but it won't know exactly.  By the time the message was handled in-browser, audio playback may have occurred a half second ago.  Some devices even have hardware codecs, adding some complexity while taking load off the CPU.

If your audio file was longer, you might have the issue of clock drift.  The audio may have been recorded at 44.1kHz, but your computer may play it back at 44.095kHz or so.  Over time that difference adds up.

Basically, you can never truly know how long a digital audio file is.  Lossy formats like MP3 make this even more complicated.  Remote files that cannot be reliably seeked mean that the player has to just guess how long a file is based on its file size and the average bitrate.  Even if you solved all of the problems, clock drift still has some effect which cannot be removed short of synchronizing with a common clock (like a GPS signal, but that's not exact either due to the atmosphere).

Comment: having the counter 50-350ms off seems to negate your theory about MP3's 13ms granularity.

Comment: @dandavis All the delays add up.  The point is that there is no one source of this error in timing.  Also, it's actually 26ms per frame.  I was using 576 samples which is the granule size for encoding, not the end frame size.

Comment: either way, having it more off then the granularity suggest a more deep-seated issue than rounding errors. plus, the same behavior exists with WAV files, and in my tests, WAVs are even more laggy when you get super-precise... i'm not saying that granularity isn't a part of the lag, but it's a small part of a bigger lag than latency alone can explain. Thus that particular issue seems unworthy of such a zoomed-in well-written analysis to the detriment/exclusion of more holistic examinations of the problem. that the OP is not using using any timing data from the audio itself is another hint.

Comment: @dandavis Admittedly, I missed the code block on the first read and thought he was using the actual audio element he created to tell him the time.  In any case, this all applies so I left it.

Comment: the answer sheds light on one of the least-known and hardest to track down sources of inaccuracy, and is valuable even if it doesn't explain 100% of the OP's problem.